# Cannot print iframe using javascript in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript

I have an action in my controller and the view is calling the java script function to get data from my asp.net session to display by ajax.

When I browsed the view in url, the data showed properly. But when I used the `iframe` with the javascript to print that view, there is no data in my PDF file that printing from the view.

This is my javascript function :

```
function printPage(sURL) {
  var oHiddFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
  oHiddFrame.src = sURL;
  oHiddFrame.style.visibility = "hidden";
  oHiddFrame.style.position = "fixed";
  oHiddFrame.style.right = "0";
  oHiddFrame.style.bottom = "0";
  document.body.appendChild(oHiddFrame);
  oHiddFrame.contentWindow.on
  oHiddFrame.contentWindow.onload = oHiddFrame.contentWindow.print;
  oHiddFrame.contentWindow.onafterprint = function () {    
      document.body.removeChild(oHiddFrame); };
}
```

Comment: Is the content of the iframe on a different domain than the parent document?

Comment: I called the javascript function that display the content of iframe in the parent of document.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Is the URL that the iframe is displaying on a different domain than the parent page that contains the iframe?

Comment: This is the URL that contain the print icon `Quote/CheckOut` and then when I click the print icon, it will call another action `Quote/PrintQuote`.

Comment: You're still not answering the question I'm asking.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @PhonicUK : I'm using the iFrame to show my data, and I'm calling it when click on the print icon, then call the print dialog like (Ctrl+P), so the iFrame will be hidden at that time. Till the PDF file is populated, the iFrame content is displayed in my PDF.

Comment: @socheata: If the `printPage` is called from *www.website1.com* and the `sURL` parameter passed to `printPage` function is *www.website2.com*, which is a different website, it won't be possible to access the child property of `contentWindow` because this violate the *cross-domain* restriction policy. Thus, the web browser will always refuse to do it and throw a JavaScript exception error.

Comment: @Jay : No, Jay. It stays in the same domain.